Why I can't sent the session from a controller to another laravel 11?
I have a resource named categories on my web.php file with the following content:
Route::prefix('admin')->middleware(['web'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('login', [AdminLoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('login', [AdminLoginController::class, 'login'])->name('admin.login.post');
    Route::post('logout', [AdminLoginController::class, 'logout'])->name('admin.logout');

    Route::middleware(['auth', 'admin'])->group(function () {
        Route::resource('categories', CategoryController::class);
        Route::post('update-category-status', [CategoryController::class, 'updateStatus'])->name('admin.updateCategoryStatus'); // This belongs to Categories

        Route::resource('products', ProductController::class);

        Route::get('dashboard', function () {
            return view('admin.index');
        })->name('admin.index'); // This is a temporary route, the dashboard will be changed later
    });
});


In my CategoryController I have the two methods:
    public function index()
    {
        Log::info('In Index Method');
        Log::info('Session Data in Index:', session()->all());

        $categories = Category::with('parent', 'children')->get();
        return view('admin.productCategory.index', compact('categories'));
    }

and my destroy method or any other method in this controller:
public function destroy(string $id)
    {

        $category = Category::find($id);


        if ($category && $category->delete()) {
            session()->flash('product_deleted', 'Category deleted successfully!');
        } else {
            session()->flash('product_not_deleted', 'Category was not deleted!');
        }
        Log::info('AFTER THIS ');
        Log::info('Session Data:', session()->all());
        session()->flash('product_deleted', 'Category deleted successfully!');

        return redirect()->route('categories.index');

    }

The index method won't receive the session value.
The logger prints the following log:
[2024-07-30 14:43:26] local.INFO: AFTER THIS   
[2024-07-30 14:43:26] local.INFO: Session Data: {"_token":"210aCSLtzRf4afNsYuzuY4xsYG1khCMf01YMc52H","url":[],"_previous":{"url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/categories"},"_flash":{"old":[],"new":["product_deleted"]},"login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d":1,"auth":{"password_confirmed_at":1722348879},"product_deleted":"Category deleted successfully!"} 
[2024-07-30 14:43:26] local.INFO: In Index Method  
[2024-07-30 14:43:26] local.INFO: Session Data in Index: {"_token":"210aCSLtzRf4afNsYuzuY4xsYG1khCMf01YMc52H","url":[],"_previous":{"url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/categories"},"_flash":{"old":["product_deleted","product_deleted"],"new":[]},"login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d":1,"auth":{"password_confirmed_at":1722348879},"product_deleted":"Category deleted successfully!"} 
[2024-07-30 14:43:27] local.INFO: In Index Method  
[2024-07-30 14:43:27] local.INFO: Session Data in Index: {"_token":"210aCSLtzRf4afNsYuzuY4xsYG1khCMf01YMc52H","url":[],"_previous":{"url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/categories"},"_flash":{"old":[],"new":[]},"login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d":1,"auth":{"password_confirmed_at":1722348879}} 

I checked kernel for anything that might be wrong but everything seems alright:
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\Localization::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,

        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

also the session.php file seems alright:
 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),


I will be able to receive the value if lets say it is within index.php like this:
public function index()
    {
        Log::info('In Index Method');
        Log::info('Session Data in Index:', session()->all());
        session()->flash('product_deleted', 'Category deleted successfully!');

        $categories = Category::with('parent', 'children')->get();
        return view('admin.productCategory.index', compact('categories'));
    }


The flash method only lasts for the next request, then that key/value is destroyed. If you need it to last longer, then use put()

@aynber Thank you really been hitting the wall for the last 6 hours all because of this ... Really thanks ... You are a legend !!!
